# How can I add nofollow tag to every post

Tags: wordpress, seo

I have simple wordpress site which contains quiz games. User go to my site `www.site.com` and there he can choose which quiz game he want to play. Every quiz game is a new post.

Every post contains copied description of a PC game (for example GTA V) and several questions. At the end user can see how many mistakes he made by answering.

The thing is, that my site contains a lot of post and every post contains copied description of a video game. Because of that **my site was banned from google search for copy content**. How can i prevent that? I should add **nofollow** tag to every post of my site? If so, how can i do that to every post at once?

Comment: Doubt your site was removed from search for the lack of a nofollow tag. Try noindexing pages of content you take from other sources. and be aware of copyright issues.

Comment: Asking for SEO advice (how to prevent it, what the reason is, if nofollow is a solution) is off-topic here, while the second question (how to add nofollow) is on-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [wp_head](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head) hook:

```
add_action('wp_head', function()
{
    if ( is_singular('your_post_type') ) :
        ?><meta name="robots" content="nofollow"><?php
    endif;
});
```

**References**:

- [is_singular()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_singular/)

Comment: But where should I add that? To functions.php?

Comment: @audiophonic Yeah! You should put it in your `functions.php`. Make sure to change `your_post_type` to your real post type.

Comment: But its not necessary to add noindex too? Another thing is that i have links to my posts on www.mysite.com. That mean google bot can go from www.mysite.com to www.mysite.com/gta-quiz and index it no matter that there is nofollow tag?